# Al agregar materiales a mis objetos en unity los muestra muy oscuros

Tags: unity2d

Estoy intentando agregar materiales a un objeto, pero cuando lo hago siempre me lo muestra muy oscuro, me pasa lo mismo con todos los materiales y no entiendo porque, no se si tengo algo mal configurado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Los materiales se muestran oscuros porque sus shaders se ven afectados por la luz. Para evitarlo tienes que poner un objeto luz en tu escena o utilizar un shader tipo Unlit.
[image: Ejemplo shader luz y sin luz]

[image: Ejemplo shader Unlit]